# R aggregate dynamically added columns with a separate function for each of them

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  v    t1   t2  t3    t4   date1        list1

1   1.0  1.4   2   0.45   3    2020-09-03   val1
1   1.0  1.6   3   0.55  3.7  2020-09-05   val2
```

How can I group by `id, v` and aggregate the columns `t1, t2, t3, t4, date1, list1` by applying a different aggregate function to each one of them. More specifically

```
t1 -> mean
t2 -> max
t3 -> mean
t4 -> max
date -> max
list1 -> join as in python's ','.join
```

So after aggregate the frame looks like:

```
id  v    t1   t2  t3    t4   date1        list1

1   1.0  1.5   3   0.5   3.7  2020-09-05   val1, val2
```

Also one more thing is, these columns could be dynamically added based on a user selection in an R shiny framework, which means all these columns that I intend to aggregate are in the dataframe but some of them may not need to be aggregated, for example user could select only `t1, date1` and not the remaining. So my aggregate parameters depend on the selected columns and I do have the column names available from user selection. So probably it makes sense if I ask that how can I build a dynamic aggregate query.

In python, I could build a dict like the one above dynamically based on user selected columns and use something like `pd.agg(**dict)`

How can I do this in R? I tried to look at dplyr::summarise and data.table but then I cannot seem to aggregate all of them at once. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A quick search brought up [`smartAgg`](https://rdrr.io/github/brooksandrew/Rsenal/man/smartAgg.html), which I have not used myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `across` to apply functions on blocks of columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id, v) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(t1, t3), mean),
             across(c(t2, t4, date1), max), 
             list1 = toString(list1), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
#     id     v    t1    t3    t2    t4 date1      list1     
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
#1     1     1   1.5   0.5     3   3.7 2020-09-05 val1, val2
```

---

If the functions, column names are all user input

```
nm1 <- c("t1", "t3")
nm2 <- c("t2", "t4", "date1")
nm3 <- c("list1")

f1 <- "mean"
f2 <- "max"
f3 <- "toString"

df1 %>%
    group_by(id, v) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(nm1), ~ match.fun(f1)(.)),
              across(all_of(nm2), ~ match.fun(f2)(.)),
              !! nm3 := match.fun(f3)(!! rlang::sym(nm3)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
#     id     v    t1    t3    t2    t4 date1      list1     
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <date>     <chr>     
#1     1     1   1.5   0.5     3   3.7 2020-09-05 val1, val2
```

---

It can be also passed as an expression and evaluated

```
expr1 <- glue::glue('across(c({toString(nm1)}), {f1});',
              'across(c({toString(nm2)}),  {f2});',
          'across(c({toString(nm3)}),  {f3})')
df1 %>% 
     group_by(id, v) %>%
     summarise(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(expr1), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
#     id     v    t1    t3    t2    t4 date1      list1     
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <date>     <chr>     
#1     1     1   1.5   0.5     3   3.7 2020-09-05 val1, val2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L), v = c(1, 1), t1 = c(1.4, 1.6), 
    t2 = 2:3, t3 = c(0.45, 0.55), t4 = c(3, 3.7), date1 = structure(c(18508, 
    18510), class = "Date"), list1 = c("val1", "val2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I build the parameters for `across` like `c(t1, t3)` and `mean` dynamically because those columns are added by user selection and I don't know them ahead.

Comment: @SomeDude I guess there is an option to get the user selected column name?  I didn't find that info in your post

Comment: yes I do have column names from user selection. But can I do `across(c("user_selected_col1", "user_selected_col2"), "mean")` ? Does `across` accept such strings for column names and aggregate functions?

Comment: @SomeDude Yes, it does.  It can accept either unquoted or quoted or numeric index

Comment: I tried this : df1 %>% 
+     group_by(id, v) %>% 
+     summarise(across(c(t1, t3), "mean"),
+               across(c(t2, t4, date1), "max"), 
+               list1 = toString(list1), .groups = 'drop') , but it gave me the error : Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x Problem with `across()` input `.fns`.
i Input `.fns` must be NULL, a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.
i Input `..1` is `across(c(t1, t3), "mean")`.
i The error occurred in group 1: id = 1, v = 1. Not to mention I haven't provided cols as "t1", "t2" etc.

Comment: @SomeDude please check my update.  I used strings as user input for both functions and column names.

Comment: It works when I don't quote the mean. But I think my problem is deeper than I thought which is to construct type of a dynamic summarise query. I can't create `across` as a separate object to pass it to `summarise`. I believe your answer provides a path at least. Thanks.

Comment: @SomeDude In my recent update, i showed a way to quote the function as well with `match.fun`.  I hope you have seen it

Comment: @SomeDude Another option is to create an expression with `paste` and then evaluate within the `summarise`.  In that case, it can be very flexible i.e. `eval(parse_expr(yourexpr))`

Comment: would you be able to write an example expression with `paste` and `eval` to pass to `summarise`?

Comment: @SomeDude you said `across` cannot be used.  any reasons